# Compilation error with gtkmm

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, gtkmm, msys

I'm trying to compile a simple helloworld programme on eclipse using gtkmm and compiling with mingw32 through mingw32.

I followed these instructions to "install" gtkmm:
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/MSWindows

I also read a lot of threads about that topic but couldn't understand why i'm not able to compile this simple program:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv);

        Gtk::Window window;
        window.set_default_size(600,400);

        return app->run(window);
}
```

Through eclipse IDE i used the

> project=>properties=>C/C++build=>settings=>pkg-config

and i enabled gtkmm-3.0.
Then i compile and i get the error:

```
Info: Configuration "Debug" uses tool-chain "MinGW GCC" that is unsupported on this system, attempting to build anyway.
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -I/mingw32/include/gtkmm-3.0 -I/mingw32/lib/gtkmm-3.0/include -I/mingw32/include/atkmm-1.6 -I/mingw32/include/gdkmm-3.0 -I/mingw32/lib/gdkmm-3.0/include -I/mingw32/include/giomm-2.4 -I/mingw32/lib/giomm-2.4/include -I/mingw32/include/pangomm-1.4 -I/mingw32/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -I/mingw32/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/mingw32/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -I/mingw32/include/gtk-3.0 -I/mingw32/include/cairo -I/mingw32/include -I/mingw32/include/pango-1.0 -I/mingw32/include/atk-1.0 -I/mingw32/include/cairomm-1.0 -I/mingw32/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -I/mingw32/include/pixman-1 -I/mingw32/include/freetype2 -I/mingw32/include/libpng16 -I/mingw32/include/harfbuzz -I/mingw32/include/glib-2.0 -I/mingw32/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/mingw32/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/mingw32/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -I/mingw32/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/mingw32/includ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp" 
..\main.cpp:1:19: fatal error: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

What is strange is that i can see in the compile log that it include everything needed for this program.

i also tried to add in

> project=>properties=>C/C++build=>settings=>tool settings=> gcc c++
>   compiler and mingw linker

the result of `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` but i get the exact same error.

It makes 2 days that i'm reading and trying the same propositions i found everywhere but coudn't get a result.
So please can someone try to help me to found a way to get this simple example to work.

thank you a lot
(ps: sorry for my mistakes)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i solved it by manually adding all this path to include (Project Prorepties > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Includes > Include Paths (-I)):

```
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\gtkmm-3.0"
"C:\msys64\mingw32\lib\gtkmm-3.0\include"
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\glibmm-2.4"
"C:\msys64\mingw32\lib\glibmm-2.4\include"
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\glib-2.0"
"C:\msys64\mingw32\lib\glib-2.0\include"
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\sigc++-2.0" 
"C:\msys64\mingw32\lib\sigc++-2.0\include"  
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\giomm-2.4" 
"C:\msys64\mingw32\lib\giomm-2.4\include"  
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\gdkmm-3.0"  
"C:\msys64\mingw32\lib\gdkmm-3.0\include"
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\pangomm-1.4"  
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\gtk-3.0"  
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\pango-1.0" 
"C:\msys64\mingw32\lib\pangomm-1.4\include" 
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\cairo"  
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\gdk-pixbuf-2.0" 
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\cairomm-1.0"  
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\freetype2"   
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\atkmm-1.6"   
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\atk-1.0" 
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\gtkmm-3.0" 
"C:\msys64\mingw32\include\glibmm-2.4"
```

(You shoud replace "C:\msys64\mingw32" with your mingw32 path)

Also add `-std=c++11` flag (Project Prorepties > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Miscellaneous > Other flags) and

```
glibmm-2.4
gtkmm-3.0
```

to (Project Prorepties > C/C++ Build > Settings > MinGW C++ Linker > Libraries (-l))